# WPF MVVM Checkbox stop Command from firing on Data Bind

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm

I have WPF MVVM application and I am currently trying to use a Checkbox that is bound to a column in a list that it is bound to. I have a EventTriggers set and the command bound to the VM. Everything fires great....Except I do NOT want the events to fire when populated from the list, ONLY when the user checks or unchecks the checkbox. See Code:

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="Transparent" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="2,0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Label Content="Active" />
        <CheckBox x:Name="CbArchiveAoi" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" IsChecked="{Binding Path=PatientAoi.AoiIsActive}">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ArchiveAoiCommand, Mode=OneWay}" 
                                       CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=CbArchiveAoi}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Unchecked">
                     <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ArchiveAoiCommand, Mode=OneWay}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=CbArchiveAoi}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </CheckBox>
    </StackPanel>

    public ICommand ArchiveAoiCommand
    {
      get { return new RelayCommand<object>(ArchiveAoiExecute, AlwaysTrueCanExecute); }
    }

    private void ArchiveAoiExecute(object obj)
    {
        string dddd = obj.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: How do you populate it from the list?

Comment: In the code above you can see the binding that is done to the IsChecked property. The PatientAoi is an object in the VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd remove the Interaction.Triggers and use the `CheckBox.Command`and`CommandParameter` properties instead.

```
<CheckBox x:Name="CbArchiveAoi"
          VerticalAlignment="Center"
          <-- snip -->
          Command="{Binding ArchiveAoiCommand, Mode=OneWay}"
          CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=CbArchiveAoi}" />
```

Comment: Mark...Thanks...Thought I had tried that. Apparently not. Thanks again!